# How to have figure (with caption) on left, text on right over an entire book

Tags: tables, floats

I'm trying to set up image on left (with centered caption) and corresponding text on right (justified and top aligned). I've tried longtable, table, minipages and wrapfig but once a second instance is done, everything is thrown out of whack and gets worse with a third. This is a kind of biographical dictionary and is about 100 pages long. I'm just getting going with LaTeX so maybe I'm missing something obvious. My question is: is this possible and how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In the mean time have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\figwithtext[3]% #1 = image #2=caption #3=text
  {
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[valign=t,width=\linewidth]{#1}
      \captionof{figure}{#2}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
      \vspace{0pt}
      #3
    \end{minipage}
    \par\smallskip
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\figwithtext{example-image}{First caption}{
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.}

\figwithtext{example-image-a}{Second caption}{The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Pieter! I removed the customised page layout (margins) I had put in the preamble and this worked great with the default book  documentclass! I'll have to play around with the margins but this looks like the road to go down. Putting stuff in the preamble like this is new to me. (BTW I inserted * after captionof to remove the "Figure N:" in the captions in case anyone wants to do that.)